# mysql replication duplicated entry

Tags: mysql, replication

Is it recommended to add the `slave-skip-errors = 1062` option into the my.cnf file?
I want to keep my data consistent.

Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: Hi Sergio, I edited your question to make it a bit clearer, so that you might get a better response. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally recommend against it. If you run into this error, something got out of sync. Skipping that error without ensuring that things are correct could result in your slave database having different results in the other columns for the primary key in question.

Find the root cause of your error, fix that.